# What's the difference between 作る、造る、創る？

Tags: homophonic-kanji

According to [jisho.org](http://jisho.org/words?jap=tsukuru&eng=&dict=edict&common=on) they have the same meaning. How to know which to use?

Comment: @Tsuyoshi_Ito I didn't know about that tag. Nice edit.

Comment: @sawa: Thanks.  I did not know, either, before I tried to tag this question with the [kanji] tag.  The auto-completer listed this tag and I learned it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one of the many cases where ancient Chinese had finer distinctions for a single concept in ancient Japanese, which lead to the same pronunciation and varied ways of writing in Japanese. As usual, there is a general one, in this case `作る` 'make'. Then, there are the specific ones: `造る` 'craft', and `創る` 'create'. Usually, the specific ones can be replaced by the general one, but not vice versa.